# How to open a http page inside your cordova container (not in browser) without inAppBrowser Plugin

Tags: javascript, cordova, browser

I want to open an external page inside my cordova app (IOS & Android both), on a click of an anchor tag.
How to achieve it ?

I already whitelist the IP address inside config.xml file.

```
<access origin="http://192.168.1.64"  subdomains="true"/>
```

Grunt server is running on port 9001
inside my HTML (index.html) I put an anchor tag :

```
<a href="http:192.168.1.64:9001/home.html">launch internal</a>
```

but it is opening in safari window.
How to do that ?

Note :: Using cordova CLI version (3.5.0-0.2.7)

Comment: I am not really sure if that works, but you could try to use jquery's load function to load the website's data into a div. Might work, not sure